# building a menu in html with content on the right

Tags: html, css

JsFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VXxmE/2/)

So I've run into two problems and I can't seem to figure out the solutions.
one: I need the content div's min height to be the height of the menu(I'd prefer not to use the min-height rule)
two: when the content div is larger than the menu I need the menu's height to be the size of the content div.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
            <li>Menu4</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
            <li>Menu4</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="content">content2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    padding: 5px 0;
    clear: both;
}
.menu{
   float:left;
    background-color: green;
}
    .menu ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin:0;
    }
.content{
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

EDIT:

After messing around on jsFiddle I have come up with [This](http://jsfiddle.net/NGtGH/), does anyone here seem to have a problem? Essentially it uses display table and display table row...

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell first">
            asdfasdf
        </div>
                <div class="cell second">
            Content 1 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell first">
            asdfasdf
        </div>
                <div class="cell second">
            Cotent 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table{
    display table;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.row{
    display: table-row;
}

.first{
    background-color:green;
}

.second{
        background-color:yellow;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both columns to have equal heights, try the [one true layout](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/) method:

[Adjusted JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/VXxmE/6/)

```
/* CSS */

.container{
    padding: 5px 0;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu, .content {
    padding-bottom: 999999px;
    margin-bottom: -999999px;
}

.menu{
   float:left;
    background-color: green;
}
    .menu ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin:0;
    }
.content{
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Min-content size....It's a matter of floats the menu and the content and apprppriate widths

*NB. Equal height for the menu when the content is a different discussion with various solutions.*

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dey53/) (rough as I'd tidy up and use `box-sizing

```
.container{
    padding: 5px 0;
    clear: both;
     background-color: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.menu{
   float:left;
    background-color: green;
    width:10%;
}
    .menu ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin:0;
    }
.content{
 float:left;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: can you give me an idea for a solution for the menu' height?

Comment: As I said there are many ways of doing it...and most of them are 'hacks'. Try searching here for equal height divs...it's a common requedt.